# Show related posts using meta query in Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I have an ACF field called sale_or_charter with three radio options – for sale, charter or new build.

Each custom post type will have one of these values – I would like to then display related posts that have the same value for the sale_or_charter field as the current page.

I can’t work out what I am doing wrong?

I have consulted the ACF documentation and it looks correct. When I remove the 'key' and 'value' - it works, but I need it filtered by posts that have the same $type as the current post.

Any help appreciated

```
<?php 
                                                       
            $type = get_field( "sale_or_charter", get_the_ID() );
                                                       
                          $args = array(
                          'post_type' => 'yachts',
                          'posts_per_page' => 3,
                          'orderby' => 'date',
                          'order' => 'DESC',
                                           
                           'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                'key' => 'sale_or_charter',
                                 'value' =>  $type
                                     )
                             ),
                           );
                                                   
              $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
                                                   
              if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) {
              
              while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post();
```

[image]

EDIT** After adding the bounty, I decided to add a screenshot and (like an idiot) immediately realised I had it set to label and not Value which is the issue.

Comment: Have you verified `$type` contains what it should?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to do that but I will try and work it out

Comment: I cant seem to work out how to do this.

Comment: @MrToad you can use `var_dump($type)` in your PHP code to view the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your field is returning the "Label" and not the field value so the database query is not comparing the correct values.

Change the "Return Value" to `Value`, see screenshot below.

[image]

---

**Recommendation**

I would also suggest excluding the current post from your results, this prevents the current post from appearing in your related items. For example...

```php
$type = get_field( 'sale_or_charter', get_the_ID() );

$my_posts = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => 'yachts',
  'posts_per_page' => 3,
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post__not_in' => [ get_the_ID() ], // Exclude current post
  'meta_query' => [
    [
      'key' => 'sale_or_charter',
      'value' =>  $type
    ]
  ]
]);
```

Comment: Thanks - I realised after about the field error but actually didn't think about the fact I was including the current post in the results so thank you